# Issue Deploying Azure App service for next js app

Tags: azure, docker, deployment, dockerfile

this is my first time deploying a app service using azure.

The app is a next js app and below is the dockerfile I used to create the image.

```
FROM node:21.1.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

However when I try to visit the site, it loads indefinitely and eventually fails. In the deployment logs I get the following errors:

```
2023-12-05T23:03:36.663Z ERROR - Container appname_0_d945e9e7 for site teacherassistant7842 has exited, failing site start
2023-12-05T23:03:36.668Z ERROR - Container appname_0_d945e9e7 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 3000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2023-12-05T23:03:36.684Z INFO - Stopping site appname because it failed during startup.
```

What may be causing this error? Additionally I have looked for a while where the container logs may be located and have not found it. Information on this would be useful as well.

Comment: Are you working in Visual Studio or VSCode?

Comment: I am using VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Next.js application using the commands below.

`npx create-next-app your-app-name`

`npm run dev`

[image]

I added the Dockerfile to the next.js application.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I was able to build and run in Docker using the commands below.

`docker build -t nextjs-app .`
`docker run -p 3000:3000 nextjs-app`

I was successfully ran the Docker image in Docker. Check below:

[image]

I have created azure container registry.

[image]

I logged in and pushed the image into ACR by using below commands.

```
az acr login --name dododoacr
docker build -t Your-ACR-Name.azurecr.io/hello:latest .
docker push helloacr4.azurecr.io/hello:latest
```

[image]

I have created a web app and connected it to ACR; it was deployed successfully. While creating the web app, follow the steps below to connect to ACR.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will try to 'npm run build' and then 'npm start' instead of 'npm run dev'. But I can not see the images you posted(dont know if this is an issue on my end or yours)

Comment: @big_haas, can you try step by step which I was given above, because I got the output like above images.

Comment: @big_haas, I added screenshot check once, once ran the npm run dev will get URL while accessing that URL will get image in browser.